# Webpage doesn't resize correctly

Tags: html, css, resize

When I resize my webpage, only the height of my webpage shrinks, causing the page to keep the same width.

This is better demonstrated in these pictures:

[This is my webpage. The webpage doesn't resize the width and therefore resizes in a weird way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLUz5.png)

[This is the walmart website. The page resizes correctly, leaving white space on each side of the content.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yw2MM.png)

How can I get my website to resize just like the walmart website, or any other professional website, does?

Comment: Your "website" seems an image.

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag Bob clearly state it was a picture of the project. Although we do like to see code and not pictures :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you forgot to put the viewport tag. within your `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your body in a container and use rem or em size when styling the container.

If you want a fix width (i.e white on both sides when it goes beyond a certain width), you can have a flexbox within a fixed sized container with max-width styling.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Would be easier to explain if you provide the html/css

Comment: So like:  <body> <div class="container"> <div class="flexbox"> </div> </div> </body> and then .container { width:120rem; height:67rem; } .flexbox{ display:flex; max-width:120rem }

Comment: Is that what you mean?